# Incorrect dimension going into convolutional layer in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have 15 images with size 28x28. Thus, my `images.shape` is (15, 28, 28). However, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected conv2d_22_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (15, 28, 28)
```

I have tried various reshaping techniques and can get this to work on one image of shape (1, 28, 28, 1). What do I do for a list of images?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the channel dimension back into your batch. Reshape to `(15,28,28,1)` or `(15,1,28,28)` depending on your configuration (default is channels last in keras).

Answer (score 0):

`numpy.expand_dims(images, axis=4)` work for me

Comment: Its good to know that it works for you, but you must also let others know why it works? This way they will know what their mistake was.

Comment: The OP did not ask about why his/her program not work, him/her want to know "What do I do for a list of images?" so I propose one.

Comment: Your answer is not only read by OP but also by other fellow programmers who might find this issue interesting. When you write an answer here, assume you are answering to a general audience and be brief.